# Is the MSE of a variable Y, composed by the sum of others, equal to the sum of the MSE of those variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

For example, let's suppose we have a person that can move along the X-axis by steps of length $l$, and that each step can be done in the positive or in the negative direction, with equal probability.

Then, if $S_N$ is the displacement after $N$ steps,
$S_N=\sum_{i=1}^N s_i$, with $s_i=\pm l$, would the mean squared error of $S_N$ be equal to the sum of the mean squared error of each variable $s_i$?

$$<(\Delta S_{N} )^2>\stackrel{?}{=}\sum_{i=1}^N <(\Delta s_{i} )^2>$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, however, using Jensen's inequality on the convex function $x^2$, you'd get 
$$<(\Delta S_{N} )^2> \geq \sum_{i=1}^N <(\Delta s_{i} )^2>$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you detail a little more how Jensen's inequality would be applied in this case?